# GTM Universal Analytics tag firing but only records pageviews in IE and Firefox

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

- Universal Analytics tag set to fire on all pages
- GTM debugger shows that it is successfully firing

However, when viewing real-time data in Google Analytics, I can only see pageviews when browsing via IE or Firefox. Chrome doesn't appear to be sending any data through to analytics despite the tag firing.

Why might this be the case?

Comment: If you view the site in chrome and inspect the network tab via the web inspector, you should be able to verify whether or not the hits are being sent.

Comment: Did you share the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the Chrome AdBlocker extension. Disabling rectified the problem.

Comment: This manifests in the console as:

GET http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT